# MVC & routing with mode-mysql and express

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am working on a project with Angular, Express and MySQL using node-mysql dependency. I have the code working but wanted to know if I can make it more modular so that I can have a cleaner `app.js` file.

Here is my current app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var app = express();

// MySQL database connection file
var connection = require('./database/connection');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());


// Development Settings
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    // This will change in production since we'll be using the dist folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
    // This covers serving up the index page
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app')));

    // ROUTES BEGIN

    // SIGNUP ROUTE    
    app.post('/signup', function(req, res){

        var body = req.body;

        var post  = {
            email: body.email,
            firstname: body.firstname,
            lastname: body.lastname,
            password: body.password2
        };
        connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post, function(err,result) {
            // Neat!
            res.json({
                'msg': 'success!'
            });
        });
        console.log(query.sql);

    });

}

module.exports = app;
```

I have a separate connection.js file which exposes connection

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'cole'
});

connection.connect();

module.exports = connection;
```

What I want is to have a separate `/routes/signup.js` file which has the SQL query for signup route and use it in `app.js`

Is this feasible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @mscdex [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/112117/9357), and currently on hold there.